# Laravel 5.2 version of whereDate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is laravel 5.2 version of the below condition:

```
->whereDate('created_at', '=', $sel_date)
```

Please note that $sel_date is in the below format :

```
$sel_date = date('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel `whereDate` method generates the following query:

```
.... WHERE DATE('created_at') = 'Y-m-d date here'
```

You can get the same query by using a raw where:

```
->where(\DB::raw("DATE(created_at) = '".$sel_date."'"));
```

**UPDATE**

A good approach is to use bindings in raw queries so the right way to write the query would be this:

```
->where(\DB::raw("DATE(created_at) = '?'", [$sel_date]));
```

When the variable $sel_date is created from you in code is not a problem using first approach, but when it is a user input can cause a `SQL Injection` if you do not use bindings ore do not sanitize user input.